# Training taking 15GB ram

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My training dataset contains a large number of images but I converted them into numpy arrays and stored them into a pickle type file and now it is of size 1.19GB and the test dataset is 181MB and my neural network is also small but when I run my CNN it takes as much as 15GBs of my RAM that too considering that I have 16GB RAM. What could be the possible explanation for this and the solution cause it takes 45mins just for completing 1 epoch.

Thanks in advance for answering...

```
def load_dataset(self,address):
    train_data = {}
    test_data = {}
    with open(address+"\dataset_facial_exp_gray_train.pickle",'rb') as f:
        train_data = pickle.load(f)
    with open(address+"\dataset_facial_exp_gray_test.pickle",'rb') as f:
        test_data = pickle.load(f)
    x_train = np.asarray(train_data["img_arrays"])
    y_train = to_categorical(np.asarray(train_data["lables"]))
    x_test = np.asarray(test_data["img_arrays"])
    y_test = to_categorical(np.asarray(test_data["lables"]))
    return x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test

def neural_network():
    x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test = load_dataset()
    x_train = np.reshape(x_train,(-1,64,64,1))/255
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test,(-1,64,64,1))/255

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64,4,(2,2),activation='relu',input_shape=(64,64,1),kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0005)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    # model.add(Conv2D(32,4,(2,2),activation='relu'))#, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0005)))
    # model.add(BatchNormalization())
    # model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    # model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))#,kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
    model.add(Dense(16,activation='relu'))#,kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(len(lables),activation='softmax'))
    def scheduler(epoch,learning_rate):
        if epoch%15==0:
            return learning_rate*0.1
        else:
            return learning_rate
    lr = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)
    adam = Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
    checkpoint = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("emotion_model/emotion_weights.h5",monitor="loss",save_best_only=True,mode='min')
    model.compile(loss=["categorical_crossentropy"],metrics=['accuracy'],optimizer=adam)
    if os.path.exists("emotion_model\emotion_weights.h5"):
        model.load_weights("emotion_model\emotion_weights.h5")
    model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=10,epochs=50,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),shuffle=True,callbacks=[lr,checkpoint])
    json_model = model.to_json()
    with open("emotion_model/model.json",'w') as f:
        f.write(json_model)
neural_network()
```

Comment: Did you batch the data or just load it all in one go?

Comment: i batched it in10 images per batch for now

Comment: It is a problem when your program is terminated by OOM (out of memory) killer. Garbage collector should free the resources if there is (enough) memory pressure.

Comment: My program is working fine, training is really slow but it works, and if I terminate the program it releases the memory too. The only problem is that it is using more memory than it should other than that it is working kinda normal. Thanks for replying - @LukaszTracewski

Comment: As process of a batch ends, delete the previous batch then load new batch

Comment: How can I do that? @AliHakimTaşkıran

Comment: @UtkarshMalkoti How do you read the dataset? Provide me the code

Comment: @AliHakimTaşkıran I have edited it and added my code

Comment: Check e.g. https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ Similar principles apply to other OS. In essence, it's perfectly normal for program / OS to allocate all available memory. If it's not in use, it's wasted. When needed by other processes, it will be released. If you want to know why it is slow profile your code.

Comment: But I am on windows os... @LukaszTracewski

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data is stored in the array of `batch`. You trained the NN by the `batch`. After the training of the batch, delete it by `del batch`. Then train new batch. The other way to reduce memory usage is using pooling methods. Add pooling layer after the convolution layers.
Split the batches by this way

```
save_directory="/content/gdrive/My Drive/Image Dataset"
liste=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
liste[0]=os.listdir()[0:50]
liste[1]=os.listdir()[50:100]
liste[2]=os.listdir()[100:150]
liste[3]=os.listdir()[150:200]
liste[4]=os.listdir()[200:250]
liste[5]=os.listdir()[250:300]
liste[6]=os.listdir()[300:350]
liste[7]=os.listdir()[350:400]
liste[8]=os.listdir()[400:450]
liste[9]=os.listdir()[450:(len(os.listdir())-1)]
```

The `liste` contains the index values of the batches. Then process the data

```
for i in range(6,10):
  out_array=[]
  for tmp in liste[i]:
      print(tmp)
      im=cv2.resize(np.array(Image.open(tmp)),(992,744))
      out_array.append(im)
  out_array=np.array(out_array).astype(np.uint8)
  [process out_array]
  del out_array
```

Comment: This is a job for garbage collector. The memory will be freed if it is needed.

Comment: I m sorry I've never done that... I don't know to do it

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Storing entire dataset in the RAM seems to causes this case

Comment: But total size of my dataset is just 1.37GB, then how is it taking 15GB RAM? @AliHakimTaşkıran

Comment: @UtkarshMalkoti I was processing 2GB's of data several years ago. As I attempt to load entire dataset into RAM, I couldn't accomplish that. It exceeded my RAM(I was using colab it has 12 GB's of RAM. I splited the data and reduced resolution of the images. [link](https://github.com/alihakimtaskiran/NatureImagesDataset)

Comment: @UtkarshMalkoti I've edited the post. See the edits